# Form of set of solutions of linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, b\in \mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda_1\neq 0$.

Show that the linear equation $\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2+\lambda_3x_3=b$ has a set of solutions of the form $\{v\}+\text{span}(v_1, v_2)$, with $v, v_1, v_2\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $v_1, v_2$ are linearly independent.

$$$$

Could you give me a hint how we could show that, since I have no idea? I don't really know how to start.

Comment: It is given that $v_1, v_2$ are linearly independent, so it is implied that $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are linearly dependent, but this is not explicitly stated. I don't like the way this question is worded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the rank of the system is one (since $\lambda_1 \neq 0$) and then the null space has dimension $2$ ($=3-1$).

To find the solution note that

$$v=\left(\frac b{\lambda_1},0,0\right)$$

is a particular solution and

$$v_1=\left(\lambda_2,-\lambda_1,0\right) \quad v_2=\left(\lambda_3,0,-\lambda_1\right)$$

are two linearly independent solutions to $\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2+\lambda_3x_3=0$ therefore all the solutions for $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ are given by

$$\{v\}+\text{span}(v_1, v_2)$$

Comment: Why is the system of rank one? Wouldn't we follow that this hold if we have $\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2+\lambda_3x_3=0$ instead of $\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2+\lambda_3x_3=b$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar The matrix associated to the system is the row vector $[\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3]$ with $\lambda_1\neq 0$ and this suffices to assert that rank$=1$.

Comment: We have to give two solutions for the homogeneous problem because the null space is $2$, or have I understood that wrong?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes bu ranl-nullity theorem, once we know that rank$=1$ we know that the null space has dimension $2$.

Comment: Ok! In general it holds that the solution is (solution of homogeneous problem) + particular solution. So, in this case it holds that the solution i given by $\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+v$. The first part is a linear combination which is an element of the span of the two solutions, i.e. $\text{span}(v_1, v_2)$. Therefore, the set of solutions is $\{v\}+\text{span}(v_1, v_2)$. Is everything correct?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes exacly those are all the solutions for the system.

Comment: Ok!! Thank you very much for your help!! :-)

Comment: Do you maybe have also an idea for my other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3449044/proof-of-properties-of-span ?

Comment: Sorry I can’t now. Maybe later.

Comment: Ok, no problem!